# clearTimeout when click anywhere in document

Tags: javascript, impress.js

I am using impress.js to make a presentation I have added autoplay successfully but now what i want is whenever someone click's anywhere on the document it should stop

```
<script>
            ready(function() {
            if (document.getElementById('launched-placeholder'))
            loadPresentation();
            if (!window.presStarted) {
            startPres(document, window);
                var api = impress();
                api.init();
                $(document).on('impress:stepenter', function(e) {
        var currentSlide = $(e.target).attr('id');

        if (currentSlide === 'step-1') {
        setTimeout(api.next, 3000);
        } else if (currentSlide === 'step-2') {
        setTimeout(api.next, 50);
        } else if (currentSlide === 'step-3') {
        setTimeout(api.next, 50);
        } 
</script>
```

i have tried many things but couldnt get it to work. please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save the reference of setTimeout to be able to clear it:

```
var myTim1= setTimeout(api.next, 3000);
```

and not

```
 setTimeout(api.next, 3000);
```

then

```
clearTimeout(myTim1);
```

On Doc Click Event:

```
document.onclick=function(){
  clearTimeout(myTim1);

};
```

Or using jQuery:

```
 $(document).click(function(){
      clearTimeout(myTim1);

    });
```

Comment: I am having trouble where to put that code can you give an example of where should i put the code in my document or the script i posted.

Comment: That code should be placed anywhere inside your page's onLoad handler. In jQuery, `<script>$(function(){/* code goes here */});</script>`

Comment: somewhere deep inside my css code there was a body property that was setting pointer events to none that was stopping the pointer events hence not clearing the timeout